# How to check that Jetty ssl configuration is working

Tags: ssl, https, jetty

I read the different answer to set an SSL and https connection with jetty.
I follow all the steps and when I launch jetty I have in the logs :

> jetty9[31330]: 2023-06-13
> 16:45:40.260:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started
> ServerConnector@7668d560{SSL,[ssl, alpn, h2, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}

So it's seems ok.
But if I try a GET request with insmonia in https I got an SSL_ERROR
in the log I see :

> 16:47:38.179:qtp1715998167-27 OPENED
> ALPNServerConnection@b2904c::DecryptedEndPoint@3499d391{:54855<->:8443,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/30000}
> 16:47:38.212:qtp1715998167-15 CLOSED
> ALPNServerConnection@b2904c::DecryptedEndPoint@3499d391{:54855<->:8443,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=31/30000}
> 16:47:38.212:qtp1715998167-15 CLOSED
> SslConnection@d0b4ffc::SocketChannelEndPoint@297abdf1{/:54855<->:8443,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=1/1,kio=-1,kro=-1}->SslConnection@d0b4ffc{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3499d391{/:54855<->:8443,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=31/30000}=>ALPNServerConnection@b2904c

And if I launch the command keytool -printcert -sslserver 0.0.0.0:8443 -v
I have :

> java.lang.Exception: No certificate from the SSL server
> at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintCert(Main.java:2736)
> at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1238)
> at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)
> at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390) Caused
> by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
> handshake_failure
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
> at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.ssl.SSLServerCertStore.engineGetCertificates(SSLServerCertStore.java:109)
> at java.base/java.security.cert.CertStore.getCertificates(CertStore.java:152)
> at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintCert(Main.java:2725)

But certificates seems installed as the command  sudo keytool -list -v -keystore  etc/keystore as I have one entry that matches my ssl certificate.

If any one has an idea of what I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Jetty Server Dump](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html#og-troubleshooting-dump) features to see your running configuration.

Double check that your keystore is sane, valid for your version of Java, and is seen by Jetty.

Don't forget, make sure your keystore is valid for the version of Java you are using (not Jetty).
The wrong certificate type, or size, can impact your ability to use that certificate from Java's point of view.

The keytool that ships with your version of Java will produce notices and warnings telling you if your keystore is valid for that version of java. (fix any notices or warnings before attempting to use it with Jetty)

For specific on what's supported on what version of Java, see
https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html

Lastly, make sure your SSL configuration on Jetty (includes/excludes of cipher suites, protocols) match what is available on your version of Java.

Of Special Note: IBM JVMs are known to have issues, as they don't follow RFC spec naming nor the OpenJDK standard naming for cipher suites.  Putting an extraordinary burden on you to be ultra specific in your include/exclude configuration for it to work properly (and exposing you to many vulnerable cipher suites)

Comment: Thanks for clue and all the check to do. May be this is the java version as the certificate was provided to me and don't know which version of java was used.